# Solution for this burr puzzle?

Tags: burr-puzzle

I am looking for help solving the burr puzzle using the pieces: 615, 792, 824, 911, 992, 1024. I have 3d printed the pieces from the [printable puzzle project](https://www.puzzlehub.org/ppp)'s starter [burr set](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4387531), which says that these pieces are part of a level 2 puzzle. Any tips, hints, solutions, or additional info about this particular puzzle would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

These are the pieces (in the order listed above):
[image]

And this is how the solution should look (a different burr puzzle using the set):
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a Blender animation showing the disassembly process for one of the two solutions. Pieces 615, 792, 824, 911, 992 and 1024 are coloured red, black, pink, white, yellow and blue respectively.

> This solution has a 2-piece key (824/992).
>  [image]
>  MP4 version [here](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/247802651096514560/1028780938445979708/burr.mp4).

> Higher-res stills from the video:
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  The Blender source scene can be obtained [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/247802651096514560/1028779558775816283/burr.blend).

Here is the other solution with the same colours:

> 3-piece key (824/992/1024). MP4 [here](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/247802651096514560/1028867959260729425/burr2.mp4), Blender scene [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/247802651096514560/1028867932782088192/burr2.blend).
>  [image]

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]